# Javascript approaches to boolean reversal

Tags: javascript, boolean-operations

The following applies to any boolean variable, but I was writing a little function in javascript which reverses the check in a given checkbox, became bored, and wondered how much I could condense it.

Started with:

```
checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.checked = (checkbox.checked ? false : true);
```

Then moved to

```
checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
checkbox.checked = !(checkbox.checked);
```

And then

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').checked ^= 1;
```

I couldn't figure out a logical unary approach, like

```
!(document.getElementById('checkbox').checked);
```

But I found that -- works, though ++ doesn't (abs val?)

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').checked--;
```

I'm also not sure if js (or any language, for that matter) supports some implicit reference to the variable on the left side of the equation, as in:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').checked = !(left.side);
```

There are usually 1000 ways of doing the same thing.. any other neat approaches? Is there a "best" approach for any reason (or most compatible from language to language)?

Comment: Yucky option thru the DOM twice `   document.getElementById('checkbox').checked = !document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;`

Comment: In your second example you don't need the parenthesis on the right side.

Comment: I like the `document.getElementById('checkbox').checked ^= 1;` option - it's creative.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin - Yeah it is. But I'm afraid most developers won't understand what's going on.

Comment: @Bart If they don't know that `^=` is a _XOR_ (or what that means) then they should look it up. I'm not saying that it is the clearest, but a dev should know their operators.

Comment: @PaulS. For the most part I agree with you. But one should always avoid complexity where it is not needed.

Comment: @Bart I have to agree with @Paul S. XOR is not complicated and if you don't know your basic bitwise operators then you should not be a developer - unless you're new to development in which case you should go learn it now.

Bitwise operations are powerful and critical to many applications. It's the same deal with using `& 1` to test if a number is odd. It's simple, efficient and really not cryptic.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin That's a very blunt statement. Someone who doesn't know bitwise operators can be a very good developer. It's like saying: "Don't know the ECU? Don't drive the car!".

Comment: @JustinWarkentin I took programming in college and followed it up with a computer science degree. In college we never heard a peep about bitwise operators except that "they exist". In university, they were repeatedly drilled into our heads. I think most developers can manage just fine without them, but they can be handy time-savers IF you have a sense of where/when they can be used. Also helpful for understanding other people's code..

Comment: You can be a developer without understanding bitwise operators, but I wouldn't say a "good" developer. I don't know, I guess I just come from a background where I've used them since I was 16 and I've written libraries that couldn't function without them. I view bitwise as a necessity for any serious programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use something like `this.checked = !this.checked` for it's the most logical and readable solution I know of. Plus it works in any language I use.

Comment: IF `this` context is obtained, the best method methinks.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - It's just for illustrating the point. No context intended.

Comment: Yep, like jQuery version: `$('#myme').prop('checked',!this.checked);` to change it to the opposite. +1 as your answer was what I was going to put in also.

Comment: @Bart I didn't have access to the object directly so couldn't use 'this', but it was considered.